# R Not Properly Summarizing Qualitative Data

Tags: r

I'm having issues getting the proper summary of a qualitative data column, in both the RGui and RStudio environments. The data in question is the "Auto" data from "An Introduction to Statistical Learning, with Applications in R" ([www.StatLearning.com](http://www.StatLearning.com)). The issue in the "name" column is present whether I use the "Auto.csv" or "Auto.data" files from the book's website. What's interesting is that the RGui correctly characterizes the "horsepower" column, but RStudio does not. Again, neither correctly characterize the "name" column. Any help to correct this situation would be greatly appreciated.

[image][image]

Comment: from what you wrote, in the first try (Rstudio) you didn't pass `na.string="?"` to the read.csv() function, and it read the horsepower column as a character vector and not as a numeric. 

It would be better if you copied the code and output instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Hi Marcelo, thank you for catching this. When you ran this, did the "name" column solve properly? Thanks again.

Comment: can you provide a link to the dataset?

Comment: I believe there is nothing wrong with the `name` column. I dont have access to the same data as you, but see the edited answer. Maybe you can set `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` so that the string (character) variables will be transformed into factors. (Note that prior to R 4.0 stringAsFactors were TRUE per default, and since then is FALSE.

Comment: The data is under the "Data Sets" section at https://www.statlearning.com/resources-first-edition. There is both a "Auto.csv" and "Auto.data" file. I had the same issue with the "name" variable using both files

Comment: doesn't `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` and `na.string="?"` solve it?

Comment: I think the change in the default stringsAsFactors with the release of R 4.0 is what's causing the issue. The current edition of the book was printed in 2017. I will modify the code when I get a chance.

Comment: hi jlakes85,  I edited my answer to better meet your question. If it solves the problem, could you kindly mark as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two unrelated issues here. One is that `horsepower` has missings values encoded as "?". `read.csv()` then reads `horsepower` as a character vector and not as numeric one. The argument `na.strings = "?"` will fix this.

The other issue is that [since version 4.0.0](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html),

> R now uses a stringsAsFactors = FALSE default, and hence by default no longer converts strings to factors in calls to data.frame() and read.table().

With that, scripts that omits the `stringsAsFactors` will have different results in older versions. Previous to version 4.0.0 it will convert to factors automatically and since 4.0.0 in will read as character per default. If you wish to convert to factors just set `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`. (Or convert it to factors later on with `as.factor()`).

The reasoning behind the change [explained in depth here](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/). The most compelling reason, in my opinion, is due to reproducibility issues when automatically converting to factors.

> When creating a factor from a character vector, if the levels are not given explicitly the sorted unique values are used for the levels, and of course the result of sorting is locale-dependent

So, if you wish to convert to factors and be sure the same script will produce the same results regardless of your locale (i.e language settings), it is advisable to manually convert to factors and set the levels explicitly.

### Example with and withtout stringsAsFactors argument

```r
url <- "https://www.statlearning.com/s/Auto.csv"
df_factor <- read.csv(url, stringsAsFactors = TRUE, na.strings = "?")
summary(df_factor)
#>       mpg          cylinders      displacement     horsepower        weight    
#>  Min.   : 9.00   Min.   :3.000   Min.   : 68.0   Min.   : 46.0   Min.   :1613  
#>  1st Qu.:17.50   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:104.0   1st Qu.: 75.0   1st Qu.:2223  
#>  Median :23.00   Median :4.000   Median :146.0   Median : 93.5   Median :2800  
#>  Mean   :23.52   Mean   :5.458   Mean   :193.5   Mean   :104.5   Mean   :2970  
#>  3rd Qu.:29.00   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:262.0   3rd Qu.:126.0   3rd Qu.:3609  
#>  Max.   :46.60   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :455.0   Max.   :230.0   Max.   :5140  
#>                                                  NA's   :5                     
#>   acceleration        year           origin                  name    
#>  Min.   : 8.00   Min.   :70.00   Min.   :1.000   ford pinto    :  6  
#>  1st Qu.:13.80   1st Qu.:73.00   1st Qu.:1.000   amc matador   :  5  
#>  Median :15.50   Median :76.00   Median :1.000   ford maverick :  5  
#>  Mean   :15.56   Mean   :75.99   Mean   :1.574   toyota corolla:  5  
#>  3rd Qu.:17.10   3rd Qu.:79.00   3rd Qu.:2.000   amc gremlin   :  4  
#>  Max.   :24.80   Max.   :82.00   Max.   :3.000   amc hornet    :  4  
#>                                                  (Other)       :368

df_string <- read.csv(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "?")
summary(df_string)
#>       mpg          cylinders      displacement     horsepower        weight    
#>  Min.   : 9.00   Min.   :3.000   Min.   : 68.0   Min.   : 46.0   Min.   :1613  
#>  1st Qu.:17.50   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.:104.0   1st Qu.: 75.0   1st Qu.:2223  
#>  Median :23.00   Median :4.000   Median :146.0   Median : 93.5   Median :2800  
#>  Mean   :23.52   Mean   :5.458   Mean   :193.5   Mean   :104.5   Mean   :2970  
#>  3rd Qu.:29.00   3rd Qu.:8.000   3rd Qu.:262.0   3rd Qu.:126.0   3rd Qu.:3609  
#>  Max.   :46.60   Max.   :8.000   Max.   :455.0   Max.   :230.0   Max.   :5140  
#>                                                  NA's   :5                     
#>   acceleration        year           origin          name          
#>  Min.   : 8.00   Min.   :70.00   Min.   :1.000   Length:397        
#>  1st Qu.:13.80   1st Qu.:73.00   1st Qu.:1.000   Class :character  
#>  Median :15.50   Median :76.00   Median :1.000   Mode  :character  
#>  Mean   :15.56   Mean   :75.99   Mean   :1.574                     
#>  3rd Qu.:17.10   3rd Qu.:79.00   3rd Qu.:2.000                     
#>  Max.   :24.80   Max.   :82.00   Max.   :3.000                     
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I think `stringsAsFactors` is the more proximal problem: perhaps you could comment on that (and the different defaults in R<4.0 and >=4.0) in your answer?

Comment: Done! I believe now it addresses the question better. Do you think it is a good idea to edit the question a bit so that more people facing this issue finds this kind of answer?? (I am still a bit unsure with the etiquette of editing other people's questions:)